# Limit of a sequence of recursive

Tags: limits

$$
d_{1} = 5 \\
d_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}(d_{n}+\frac{5}{d_{n}}) 
$$
What is the limit of that sequence and why?
Could someone give me a hint as to how to start this problem?

Comment: what is $e_n$, do you mean $d_n$? I think $\sqrt 5$ would be the answer,provided I understand the question.

Comment: Yes, I mean $d_{n}$. Writing error.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

1. Use induction to show $\sqrt{5}\leq d_n\leq 5, \forall n$
2. consider $d_{n+1}-d_n$ to show $d_n$ is monotone, hence by Monotone convergence theorem, the limit exists, $\lim_{n\to\infty}d_n=d>0$.
3. Pass $n$ to $\infty$, $d = \frac{1}{2}(d+\frac{5}{d})$. Solve the equation and select suitable $d$.

Answer (score 0):

From a purely algebraic point of view, consider solving $$f(x)=x^2-a=0$$ using Newton starting iterations at $x_1$. The iterative scheme is $$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$ which, for your case, write $$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{x_n^2-a}{2x}=\frac 12(x_n+\frac {a}{ x_n})$$ which is your relation.

So basically, you are solving $x^2-5=0$ starting at $x=5$.